# Realizacion de una consulta en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Esto es parte de mi codigo en el cual estoy realizando la consulta con la base de datos 
el cual lo estoy realizando en un menu (NavegationDrawerActivity), anterioremente  lo he realizando en un Empty Activity  y asi sin detalles y errores.

LA forma de programacion en un  (NavegationDrawerActivity y  Empty Activity) es diferente?
Ya que no cierra la aplicacion pero no muestra los datos que quiero

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String URL_players="http://127.0.0.1/players.php";
    List<usuario> playersList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)root.findViewById(R.id.rvconsulta);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        playersList= new ArrayList<>();
        loadplayers();

        homeViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {

            }
        });
        return root;
    }
    private void loadplayers() {


        StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_players, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject usuarios = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        playersList.add(new usuario(
                                usuarios.getInt("id"),
                                usuarios.getString("nombre"),
                                usuarios.getString("especialidad"),
                                usuarios.getString("turno"),
                                usuarios.getString("imagen")
                        ));
                    }
                    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), playersList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

El detalle es el siguiente al iniciar la aplicacion no muestra nada 
genera errores como el siguiente :

E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
Could not find class 'androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$SharedElementCallback21Impl', referenced from method androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.setEnterSharedElementCallback